# How do i find(or calculate) the Height of the Header in the Word document (OPEN XML)?

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk, wordml

Is there a way i can find the height of header for each page in a word document . Currently there seems to be no way which lets us find the header height ?

Is there any other way i can go about this ? I tried with the pageMargin but nothing in that leads to finding the height of the header content ?

Answer (score 1):

Height of the header or a footer can be found in the [Section Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.sectionproperties.aspx).

Within the section properties you'll find an XML element .

The header attribute of that element specifies the header height.